# Oracle 11g, XML

Tags: xml, oracle

I am working on Oracle 11g and table structure is

```
ID - NUMBER
xmlCOL - CLOB
```

This is my XML data in the table

```
<DEPARTMENT ID="10" NAME="ACCOUNTING">
    <EMPLOYEES>
        <EMPLOYEE>
            <ID>7934</ID>
            <NAME>MILLER</NAME>
        </EMPLOYEE>
    </EMPLOYEES>
</DEPARTMENT>
```

Is it possible that I can find the node details based on the value I provide? For e.g.

Can I search for value MILLER and it returns the node viz. `/DEPARTMENT/EMPLOYEES/EMPLOYEE/NAME`?

Comment: Yes, it Is possible. But did you do something yourself?

Comment: What do you consider being a "node"? The `<department>`? The `<employee>`? The `<name>`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz, I wrote a big function with INSTR and SUBSTR's to get all the nodes. When I pass value "7934" as parameter in the function, it will return me /DEPARTMENT/EMPLOYEES/EMPLOYEE/ID and when I pass value "MILLER" as parameter, it will return /DEPARTMENT/EMPLOYEES/EMPLOYEE/NAME.



I have been searching hard to find if there is a built-in in Oracle 11g to get the same output.



My actual XML is different. This is just a practice XML. That is a bit lengthy.

Answer (score 0):

You can to use `extractvalue` to get value of node and use it into `where` expression -

```
with t as 
(
    select xmltype('
        <DEPARTMENT ID="10" NAME="ACCOUNTING">
            <EMPLOYEES>
                <EMPLOYEE>
                    <ID>7934</ID>
                    <NAME>MILLER</NAME>
                </EMPLOYEE>
                <EMPLOYEE>
                    <ID>123123</ID>
                    <NAME>JOHN</NAME>
                </EMPLOYEE>
            </EMPLOYEES>
        </DEPARTMENT>
    ') as xml_
    from dual
)
select column_value as node, extractvalue(column_value, '/*/NAME') as name, extractvalue(column_value, '/*/ID') as id
  from t, table(xmlsequence(EXTRACT(t.xml_, '/DEPARTMENT/EMPLOYEES/*'))) s
where extractvalue(column_value, '/*/NAME') = 'MILLER'
```